# validate_data error when implementing SMOTE

Tags: python, machine-learning, smote

I am using SMOTE to oversample my imbalanced dataset, and keep running into a

`AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute '_validate_data'`

My sample dataframe and code is as such

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'field_one': [41, 32, 53, 100, 22, 234, 35, 543, 31, 46], 
    'field_two': [15, 12, 90, 100, 45, 345, 310, 67, 76, 78],
    'field_three': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'classes': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
})
oversample = SMOTE(sampling_strategy="auto")
X = df.drop(['classes'], axis=1)
y = df.classes
X_resampled, y_resampled = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

I have tried changing the SMOTE instantiation to take in a float for `sampling_strategy` instead

```
oversample = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.2)
```

but the error persists.

Comment: Perhaps try to upgrade your `scikit-learn` as shown [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/723)

Comment: Yup that worked! Thanks @IvanWiryadi